# Geofencing & import points in geojson-format in Xcode4

Tags: xcode4, geojson, geofencing

We are trying to build our first iphone-app in Xcode 4. Our idea is to use the technique of geofencing. So far we have created a database in google (in geojson format) with 20 locations with lat/long coordinates, information and name. We want to import this file as a layer in xcode were we can see each point on the map. How can we do this?

After figuring out how to import the points we also want to create a radius surrounding each point that will trigger an event when the user is entering the radius.

The app so far is a map showing the users location.

We hope you can give us some guidance in the right direction!